# Why does a linear regression in time series forecasting does not provide a line in predictions?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, time-series, forecasting

I'm reading the [TensorFlow Time series forecasting tutorial](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/structured_data/time_series) trying to perform my own time series prediction.
However, specifically on single-shot models section for multiple time steps, the Linear model is implemented as a Dense layer without the activation. I have two questions regarding this:

1. In my understanding, this is equivalent as a linear regression. Is that correct?
2. Why does the model doesn't provide a line as the predictions?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You'd better ask this in https://datascience.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Thanks @FarhoodET! I will.